# How do I get a view part instance in an Eclipse e4 application?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to get the instance of a view part in an Eclipse e4 application but I can't find the PlatformUI class. Has the name changed since Eclipse 3 or is it located in a different package?

Comment: Paul Webster kindly helped me, giving me the right API to call. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 11):

When looking at [Eclipse e4 Parts](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4RCP/article.html#parts):

[image: e4 parts]

bugs like [371405](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371405) can be instructive:

### org.eclipse.ui.presentations

> This API no longer works in 4.2, and we never intend to make it work.
>   It is incompatible with the pluggable rendering story in 4.2. Decisions that could once be made by the presentation extensions are now up to the renderer.
>
> Affected API that needs deprecation:
>
> - Entire API package: `org.eclipse.ui.presentations`
> - Extension point:`org.eclipse.ui.presentationFactories`

```
    org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants#PRESENTATION_FACTORY_ID
    org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer#getPresentationFactory
    org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer#setPresentationFactory
```

The rest of the Tutorial explains how to declare "parts" (editors or views)

---

The [OP August Karlstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337149/august-karlstrom) mentions:

> This used to work:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("‌​some view");
```

Using a singleton like PlatformUI is a bad practice and one of the reason of the introduction, in e4, of **[Context](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Contexts)**. See this [presentation on Context](http://www.eclipse.org/e4/resources/contexts.pdf).

---

[Paul Webster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713646/paul-webster) (IBM Eclipse Platform team member) comments:

> In Eclipse4 you would use `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService.findPart(String)` to find an `MPart` by ID.
>   The `MPart` contains the injected part in its object property.

As the page [Workbench_Services](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/EAS/Workbench_Services) details:

> In e4, the notion of a workbench page will not be present.
>   The **[part service API](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295003)** will essentially be a merge of the existing 3.x `IPartService` and `WorkbenchPage` interfaces.

---

Note that this isn't ideal, as [bug 372488](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372488) illustrates (following [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/297595/)):

> An `MPart` for an `MPartDescriptor` is created with `EPartService.createPart(descriptor_id)`, where descriptor_id is the identifier of the `MPartDescriptor`.
>   This part can be found again with `EPartService.findPart(descriptor_id)` -- **if there is only one**.
>
> The problem is, that one may need do create more than one `MPart` for one `MPartDescriptor`.
>   An editor may be one example: one may want to edit different instances of one and the same kind.
>
> The creation of more than one `MPart` for a given `MPartDescriptor` is possible, but there is no convenient method to find these parts.
>   `EPartService.findPart(descriptor_id)` will return the first `MPart` created for a particular `MPartDescriptor`, even if there is more than one.
>   So there are three problems, for a given MPartDescriptor:
>
> 1. `EPartService.findPart(id)` does not tell that there is more than one `MPart`.
> 2. There is no convenient way to get all `MParts` for this descriptor.
> 3. There is no API-way to get the particular `MPart` for given descriptor and "content" or "reference".
>
> Currently the way to go is using `EPartService.getParts()` which unfortunately
>   returns all `MPart`s, not only those corresponding to one particular
>   `MPartDescriptor`.
>   Then one would need to check, whether there is one `MPart` for the particular `MPartDescriptor` having a particular "content".
>
> So something is missing that will find an `MPart` for a given `MPartDescriptor`
>   with particular "content" or "reference".

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still don't know how to get the view for a given view ID. This used to work: `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("some view");`

Comment: In Eclipse4 you would use `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService.findPart(String)` to find an MPart by ID.  The MPart contains the injected part in its `object` property.

Comment: @PaulWebster Thank you, Paul, for the tip. I have a hard time finding snippets or examples with this technique. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and have added a few references involving `EPartService`.

Answer (score 5):

Just have the same question. After found this thread and tried with:

```
MPart mPart = epartService.findPart("MyPart");

MyPart myPart = (MyPart)mPart.getObject();
```

then I got my view part.